# ¿Qué características debe tener el HTML y CSS para ser responsive y visualizado correctamente por clientes de correo?

Tags: html, css

Debo maquetar una plantilla HTML para ser enviada como correo electrónico.

¿Qué consideraciones técnicas debe tener el HTML y CSS para que se visualize correctamente en los clientes de correo?

Comment: Creo que es una pregunta válida pero se podría redactar mejor para conseguir una buena respuesta, crees que la puedo editar?

Comment: si amigo claro dale @CarlosMuñoz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En el caso de las responsivas, utilizaremos media queries pero recordando el limitado soporte a hojas de estilo en la mayoría de clientes, recuerda usar las formas completas de los estilos y no sus formas reducidas.

Puedes tomar esta plantilla sencilla como [ejemplo](https://github.com/leemunroe/responsive-html-email-template)

**Posdata,** los emails responsivos son compatibles con:

- La aplicación de correo de iOS
- La aplicacion de correo de Android 4.x
- La aplicacion de correo de Windows Phone 7.5 en adelante

No soportada en:

- La aplicación de Gmail
- La aplicación de Yahoo Mail

Finalmente, puede serte útil recordar los principios básicos del diseño de plantillas de correos:

- Para organizar tu plantilla, es recomendable utilizar tablas por ser altamente compatibles. Y es recomendable que tengan un ancho máximo de entre 600 y 650 píxeles.
- Ya sabemos que la mayoría de buzones de correo bloquean las imágenes y que el lector no las verá si no pulsa el botón ‘Mostrar imágenes’. Así que, de antemano, tenemos que suponer que nuestro destinatario no verá las imágenes, por lo que debemos diseñar el email con esa idea.
- Gmail y otros buzones de correo no soportan estilos en cascada (CSS), así que mejor dejarlos de lado. Además, muchos buzones sólo dan soporte a los estilos más básicos de HTML (font-family, font-weight, etc) y no soportarán estilos avanzados (clear, float, z-index, etc).
- Otro consejo a la hora de dar formato es evitar formas cortas de código; se debe escribir entero.

Es decir escribir:

```
td{
margin-left:15px;
margin-rigth:15px;
margin-top:15px;
margin-bottom:15px; 
}
```

En vez de

```
td{
margin:15px;
}
```

Comment: con usar las formas completas de los estilos y no sus formas reducidas te refieres ah?

Comment: Ya lo edite, gracias por la observación.

Answer (score 3):

Es claro que es limitado la implementación de etiquetas para crear una plantilla de Correo por motivos de seguridad y otra para que nuestro contenido que enviamos no se vea mal visualmente.

En el siguiente link puedes encontrar recomendaciones sobre que etiquetas html implementar, soporte a estilos css y recomendaciones de la cantidad de imagenes que contiene nuestra plantilla, te sugiero que tengas en cuenta las siguientes sugerencias:

- Utilizar tablas, la tabla puede tener tanto filas como columnas que necesites, recomendable que tengan un ancho máximo de entre 600 y 650 píxeles.
- Utilizar estilos básicos de HTML(font-family, font-size, font-weight).
- Para contener textos utiliza `<td>`, ya que etiquetas como `<p>` o `<h1>` pueden causarnos algunos inconvenientes.
- Puedes utilizar eventos como  `mouse_over` u `hover` para efectos en enlaces, aunque puede que no en todos los buzones puede funcionar.
- Para cambiar el color de los enlaces puede utilizar etiquetas  entre  y  para modificar el formato.

Para imágenes las recomendaciones son:

- Tu email sin imágenes también es efectivo (los buzones de correo las bloquearán a priori).
- Las imágenes incluyen el atributo alt.
- Las imágenes son .GIF o .JPEG (evitar .PNG).
- El valor border es 0.
- Incluye `style=”display:block;”` a las imágenes para evitar espacios debajo de ellas.
- Las imágenes incluyen los atributos de alto y ancho (height y width).
- Utiliza referencias absolutas y no relativas (usar `src=”www.misitio.es/imagenes/logo.gif”` en lugar de `src=”/imagenes/logo.gif“`).
- Outlook no soporta imágenes de fondo.

Se deben evitar utilizar:

- No utilizar vídeos
- No utilizar flash
- No utilizar formularios
- No utilizar capas con etiquetas `<div>`.
- No utilizar adjuntos

Por último verifica la fuente que se esta implementado, algunas de las tipografías estándares más seguras son estas:

- Arial – Arial
- Tahoma – Tahoma
- Trebuchet MS – Trebuchet MS
- Verdana – Verdana
- Georgia – Georgia
- Times New Roman – Times New Roman
- Times – Times
- Courier – Courier
- Andale mono – Andale mono
- Comic Sans MS – Comic Sans MS

Saludos.